# Am I Doing something wrong in UPI intent using URL schemes in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, url, android-intent, upi

The following is my intent string or URL for opening PhonePe app

> phonepe://upi://pay?pa=Motilal2005@hdfcbank&pn=MOFSL&mc=6021&tr=uft_2288932c6345a5&tn=Pay%2520to%2520MOFSL&mode=03&am=100&cu=INR

The following is my intent string or URL for opening GPay app

> tez://upi://pay?pa=Motilal2005@hdfcbank&pn=MOFSL&mc=6021&tr=uft_2288daf8bd45a5&tn=Pay%2520to%2520MOFSL&mode=03&am=100&cu=INR

Please tell me if I am doing something wrong in the URL schemes as I am getting a error when I click Proceed to Pay in the PhonePe or GPay app.

When I click on Proceed to Pay in the GPay or the PhonePe app the app should add funds to the respective UPI account and I should get a success message as true.

Answer (score 0):

I did some editing and now the URLs are working fine .....

The working URL for PhonePe is
phonepe://upi/pay?pa=Motilal2005@hdfcbank&pn=MOFSL&am=2&cu=INR&tn=Pay to MOFSL .

And working URL for GPay is
tez://upi/pay?pa=Motilal2005@hdfcbank&pn=MOFSL&am=2&cu=INR&tn=Pay to MOFSL .

Please replace the respective parameters with your parameters.

Comment: Does payment gets successful?